# SQL command with if not right

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I'm having problems with my SQL command. This method receives a parameter value but always ends up returning the value of the last if.

How can I solve this? Case?

Thank you

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_ResponsavelRisco] (@idDiretoria AS INT = NULL, @idArea AS INT = NULL, @idSubArea AS INT = NULL )
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @RETORNO INT

   SET @RETORNO = 0

   IF ISNULL(@idDiretoria,'') <> '' 
     SET @RETORNO = @idDiretoria

   IF ISNULL(@idArea,'') <> ''
     SET @RETORNO = @idArea

   IF ISNULL(@idSubArea,'') <> ''   
     SET @RETORNO = @idSubArea

   RETURN @RETORNO
END
```

Don't work.. If parameter is @idDiretoria work right but if parameter is @idArea don't work.

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_ResponsavelRisco] (@idDiretoria AS INT = NULL, @idArea AS INT = NULL, @idSubArea AS INT = NULL )
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @RETORNO INT

    SET @RETORNO = 0

    IF @idDiretoria IS NOT NULL
     SET @RETORNO = @idDiretoria

   IF @idArea IS NOT NULL
     SET @RETORNO = @idArea

   IF @idSubArea IS NOT NULL
     SET @RETORNO = @idSubArea

   RETURN COALESCE( @idDiretoria, @idArea, @idSubArea, 0 )

END
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: `RETURN COALESCE( @idDiretoria, @idArea, @idSubArea )` without `if`s.

Comment: @danihp - That has different semantics if any of the parameters are an empty string.

Comment: Actually no it doesn't. All the parameters are `INT`. An empty string will be coerced to `0` anyway but in that case the semantics will differ if any are `0`...

Comment: either look at danihp's comment ( better way ) or do not set the value within the IF but RETURN within that IF. Then it should check the way you intended. Nargl. And please... use IF IS NOT NULL instead of your IFNULLs

Comment: Why are you using ISNULL with INT and VARCHAR arguments? I don't even know what happens then. Make your code clear and maybe the bug goes away just from that alone.

Comment: @MartinSmith, posted as answer with same semantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here with the same semantic:

```
RETURN COALESCE( NULLIF(@idDiretoria, ''), 
                 NULLIF(@idArea, ''),
                 NULLIF(@idSubArea, '' )
```

But, perhas, it is enough as:

```
RETURN COALESCE( @idDiretoria,
                 @idArea, 
                 @idSubArea)
```

you can read @Matthew and MartinSmith comments below.

Comment: +1 but there is no need to check for empty strings on the `INT` type.

Comment: Thanks Mattew, I know, but it seems that this is and OP requirement, just see they comment.

Comment: Ok, I explain it in answer.

Comment: @Matthew - Checking for empty strings on the int type is the same as checking for zero. `SELECT CASE WHEN '' = 0 THEN 'Yes' END` doesn't seem like the OP would have any good reason for doing it that way so I assume it is unintentional.

Comment: @MartinSmith but using the `INT` type his null check is awkwardly checking against a disparate type.

Comment: @Matthew - I don't disagree. The last half of my previous comment indicates that.

Comment: @danihp you have them in the wrong order and you need to return the zero.

Comment: @danihp your `COALESCE` will return @idDirectoria if it's `NOT NULL` regardless of the other parameters. The OP's code should return @idSubArea if that value is `NOT NULL` ... and it should return zero if all values are `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your `ISNULL` is using disparate types for strings and `INT`s

**EDIT:** If you provide @idSubArea then you should always expect that to be the returned value regardless of whether or not you send the other two parameters. You have *prioritized* the return values in the following rank:

1. @idSubArea
2. @idArea
3. @idDirectoria

Any higher ranking parameter will be returned, regardless of lower ranking parameters.

Your function indicates they're all `INT` so why check for a blank string?

You can try this: if you want to keep the same `IF` structure (I assume you have more logic than you actually pasted here)

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_ResponsavelRisco] (@idDiretoria AS INT = NULL, @idArea AS INT = NULL, @idSubArea AS INT = NULL )
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @RETORNO INT

   SET @RETORNO = 0

   IF @idDiretoria IS NOT NULL
     SET @RETORNO = @idDiretoria

   IF @idArea IS NOT NULL
     SET @RETORNO = @idArea

   IF @idSubArea IS NOT NULL
     SET @RETORNO = @idSubArea

   RETURN @RETORNO
END
```

If you don't have more logic then the suggestion by @danihp in the comments section is valid and he should turn it into an answer, though he has the wrong order, see corrected below:

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_ResponsavelRisco] (@idDiretoria AS INT = NULL, @idArea AS INT = NULL, @idSubArea AS INT = NULL )
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN

   RETURN COALESCE( @idSubArea, @idArea, @idDiretoria, 0)    

END
```

Comment: @ConradFrix fair enough... but that is exactly the behavior we'd expect if all parameters are provided.

Comment: @ConradFrix you're completely right, edited answer. I had them in the wrong order.

Comment: @Matthew thank you for help! But don't work
 
 
 SELECT [idPonto], [RE]
  FROM [DataBase].[dbo].[Ponto]
  INNER JOIN [DataBase].[dbo].[Area_Usuario_Aux]
  ON   [DataBase].[dbo].[f_ResponsavelRisco](Ponto.idDiretoria, Ponto.idArea, Ponto.idSubArea) = Area_Usuario_Aux.idArea
  WHERE  Area_Usuario_Aux.RE = 'Milena'